# adding a small feature to jCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I just finished working with jCarousel and it works fine, however my client needs to add one more thing. Please check this out: http://sneakyrascal.com/coupon2/
You can see "Σελίδα 1/5" at the top of the content slider which refers to 5 pages and has to be changed with the current page. I haven't found a way to do that, is it possible to add this feature to jCarousel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already been solved, for those who want the answer:

```
$(function(){
  $(".jcarousel-next-horizontal").click(function(){
    var currentTime = Date.now();
    var lastClickTime = $(this).data("lastClickTime");
    if (lastClickTime && (currentTime - lastClickTime < 500)) {
         return(false);   // ignore the click
    }
    $(this).data("lastClickTime", currentTime);   // record time of last click
    var currentValue = $(".pages").text();
    var five = "5";
    var newValue = parseInt(parseFloat(currentValue)) + 1;
    $(".pages").text(newValue);
    if (currentValue==five) {
      $(".pages").text("5");
    }
  });

  $(".jcarousel-prev-horizontal").click(function(){
    var currentTime = Date.now();
    var lastClickTime = $(this).data("lastClickTime");
    if (lastClickTime && (currentTime - lastClickTime < 500)) {
         return(false);   // ignore the click
    }
    $(this).data("lastClickTime", currentTime);   // record time of last click
    var currentValue = $(".pages").text();
    var newValue = parseInt(parseFloat(currentValue)) - 1;
    var one = "1";
    $(".pages").text(newValue);
    if (currentValue==one) {
      $(".pages").text("1");
    }
  });
});
```